# Django template block code does not work when included as a snippet

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I want to change the state of the navbar as highlighted in different pages.
When I am normally placing the nav-bar in base.html and add a block content it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>

<title>Dashboard</title>
{% include 'snippets/css.html' %}
</head>
<body>
        <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
        <nav id="sidebar">


            <ul class="list-unstyled components">

                <li{% block nav_live %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'live_now' %}"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>Live Now</a>
                </li>
                <li{% block nav_out %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'outcome' %}"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs" aria-hidden="true"></i>Outcome Score</a>
                </li>
                <li {% block nav_customer %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'customer_search' %}"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Customer search</a>
                </li>
                <li {% block nav_journey %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-map-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Journey Shaping</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'persona' %}">-Persona</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Outcomes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Action Maps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Auto Responses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
               <li {% block nav_analytics %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="#analyticsmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Analytics</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="analyticsmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">-Visitor Activity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Visit History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Action Map Performance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Interactions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li{% block nav_settings %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="#settingsmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons md-18" >tune</i>Settings</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="settingsmenu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'set_phone' %}">-Phone Number</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'track_code' %}">-Tracking Code</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Action Map Performance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Interactions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li{% block nav_people %}{% endblock %}>
                    <a href="#peoplemenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">people</i>People</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="peoplemenu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'teams' %}">-Team Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Visit History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Action Map Performance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">-Interactions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>


{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>
{% include 'snippets/js.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

In live_now.html I add the class="active" and it works

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block nav_live %}
class="active"
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
```

but when I try to include nav-bar as a snippet in base.html, class="active" is not rendered in the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>

<title>Dashboard</title>
{% include 'snippets/css.html' %}
</head>
<body>
{% include 'snippets/nav.html' %}


{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>
{% include 'snippets/js.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because include is not the same as extends. The first case works because you're extending the base template, but you're not extending the nav snippet. One way around it, using the same structure as you've already built, is to make nav extend base, and then all the sub templates extend nav.